# How can I pivot this data using a cte or the pivot syntax?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, pivot

Let's say I have these two tables in an MSSQL-Database:
[image]

Is there any way to create a query that result in a table like this?
[image]

There is no case where there are multiple Leader/Assistant in the **TEAMS**-Table. Both of these only occur once per project.

Comment: Please review this Q&A to get help: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do this, including those suggested by the question title, but I find a conditional `MAX()` the simplest to grok (and most likely to only ever access any table once). You want one row per `idproject`/`nameproject`, and then you need to find the team row that has the specific task associated with it. You could just as easily use `MIN()` instead of `MAX()`, if you trust your data it will be the same, if you don't trust your data that will just determine how to break ties.

```
SELECT
  p.idproject,
  p.nameproject,
  leader    = MAX(CASE t.taskTeam WHEN 'leader'    THEN t.nameTeam END),
  assistant = MAX(CASE t.taskTeam WHEN 'assistant' THEN t.nameTeam END)
FROM dbo.PROJECT AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.TEAMS AS t -- plural but project is not?
ON p.idproject = t.idproject
WHERE t.taskTeam IN ('leader', 'assistant')
GROUP BY p.idproject, p.nameproject
ORDER BY p.idproject;
```

*Note: I assumed `assistent` was a typo, and that `taskTeam` is `varchar`.*

Comment: That's just awesome! Thanks a lot for the quick help! And yes, `assistent` was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with cte's (common table expressions). By breaking up the Teams table based on the taskteam column, then joining them together on the idproject column:

```
    with leaders as (select idproject, nameTeam
                     from teams
                    where taksteam = 'leader'),
    assistants as (select idproject, nameTeam
                     from teams
                    where taksteam = 'assistant'),
    poor_guys as (select idproject, nameTeam
                     from teams
                    where taksteam = 'poor guy')


    select p.*, l.name, a.name, pg.name
    from project p
    left join leaders l on p.idproject = l.idproject
    left join assistants a on p.idproject = l.idproject
    left join poor_guys pg on p.idproject = pg.idproject
    order by p.name_project
```

If you've got more than three people in a team, you are going to run into additional complications though - you'll want to use the rank() function to further seperate out your teams' roles.